# Cannot get jQuery floatThead to work on table embedded in tabbed layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I gave up on trying to get my previous attempts to work properly on fixed header on scrollable tables, and I resorted to this plugin:
http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

Our web interface at my work displays tables for this particular view in two ways -- with tabs  or just the table outright.

Here's the structure WITH tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane  active" id="tab1">
    ... a couple stuff
    <table  id='resizable118' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0' Width='75%' leftmargin='50' >
        ... stuff in the table every row has font size of 3 but that's it
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the structure without tabs:

```
<table  id='resizable118' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0' Width='75%' leftmargin='50' >
     ... stuff in the table every row has font size of 3 but that's it
</table>
```

As you can see, the tables are generated *exactly the same way* for both. The ONLY differences are the two `<div>` elements enclosing the table for the tabbed view.

The plugin instructs to wrap the table in something like a div element. When I wrap the table with a div element when tabs are NOT used and then activate the plugin, everything turns out ok.

Problem: Regardless of whether I wrap the table with a new div element or use one of the existing `<div>` elements when USING TABBED VIEW, the table breaks.

The table header and body get squished horizontally and then none of the columns will line up afterwards. When I destroy the plugin use, everything returns to normal.

Has anyone seen this before with jQuery floatThead? What can I do to address the issue with the tabbed table view?

Comment: I am the author of the plugin. I can help you if you can show me a jsfiddle reproducing this issue. Its hard to tell exactly what is going on from the question

Comment: It's all good - I managed to fix it a couple weeks back.

Comment: @mkoryak as you are here any way to make it work with the tfoot as well ?

Comment: floating the tfoot is not possible with the plugin. see: https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead/issues/27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from documentation (http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) there is a "reflow" method,

so, add onclick event to the tab which containing that table,

```
onclick="$table.floatThead('reflow');"
```

i made in this way works :)

Comment: `$('#data-table').floatThead('reflow')` Still it is not working for me. Can you please draft the complete answer, in case you claim to know it?